# Eloquent ManyToMany Relationship Issue: Cardinality violation

Tags: php, eloquent, relationship, laravel-5

I have 3 tables one is a link table between the other two. A simple Many To Many Link.

```
videos (Table fields shortened for brevity)
+----+---------------------+
| id | name                |
+----+---------------------+
|  1 | test                |
|  2 | Test Subscription 1 |
+----+---------------------+

subscriptions
+----+--------+
| id | name   |
+----+--------+
|  1 | News   |
|  2 | Sports |
|  3 | Gospel |
|  4 | Kids   |
+----+--------+

subscription_video (link table between both models)
+----+-----------------+----------+
| id | subscription_id | video_id |
+----+-----------------+----------+
|  1 |               1 |        2 |
+----+-----------------+----------+
```

Migration used to create link table

```
Schema::create('subscription_video', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('subscription_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('subscription_id')->references('id')->on('subscriptions');
    $table->integer('video_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
    $table->foreign('video_id')->references('id')->on('videos');
});
```

Eloquent Model

```
class Video extends Model {

    use SoftDeletes;

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
     */
    public function subscriptions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Subscription');
    }

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
     */
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category');
    }
}
```

Now as per documentation i should be able to simply retrieve results via a call to

```
Video::has('subscriptions')->get()
```

Actual view code (same error occurs with or without the orderBy)

```
public function index()
{
    $videos = Video::has('subscriptions')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
    return view('subscription.video.index', ['videos' => $videos ]);
}
```

Which in should in this case return 1 result set with video_id 2. But no matter what i try i keep getting

```
SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 9 column(s) (SQL: select `id`, `name` from `videos` where `videos`.`deleted_at` is null and (select * from `subscriptions` inner join `subscription_video` on `subscriptions`.`id` = `subscription_video`.`subscription_id` where `subscription_video`.`video_id` = `videos`.`id`) = 1)
```

I don't know what i am doing wrong with these relationships and how to make Eloquent return the correct results ?

Any assistance would be appreciated.

`1. in Connection.php line 620
 2. at Connection->runQueryCallback('select * from`videos`where`videos`.`deleted_at`is null and (select * from`subscriptions`inner join`subscription_video`on`subscriptions`.`id`=`subscription_video`.`subscription_id`where`subscription_video`.`video_id`=`videos`.`id`) >= 1 order by`id`desc', array(), object(Closure)) in Connection.php line 576
 3. at Connection->run('select * from`videos`where`videos`.`deleted_at`is null and (select * from`subscriptions`inner join`subscription_video`on`subscriptions`.`id`=`subscription_video`.`subscription_id`where`subscription_video`.`video_id`=`videos`.`id`) >= 1 order by`id`desc', array(), object(Closure)) in Connection.php line 293
 4. at Connection->select('select * from`videos`where`videos`.`deleted_at`is null and (select * from`subscriptions`inner join`subscription_video`on`subscriptions`.`id`=`subscription_video`.`subscription_id`where`subscription_video`.`video_id`=`videos`.`id`) >= 1 order by`id`desc', array(), true) in Builder.php line 1377
 5. at Builder->runSelect() in Builder.php line 1367
 6. at Builder->getFresh(array('*')) in Builder.php line 1354
 7. at Builder->get(array('*')) in Builder.php line 380
 8. at Builder->getModels(array('*')) in Builder.php line 162
 9. at Builder->get() in SubscriptionVideoController.php line 33
 10. at SubscriptionVideoController->index()`

Comment: Show the real code you're trying to run. `Video::has()->get()` is not the one for this query.

Comment: @jarek-tkaczyk 
When i call `Video::has('subscriptions')->get()` the Cardinality error is the exception thrown. The full code is

`public function index()
 {
  $videos = Video::has('subscriptions')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
     return view('subscription.video.index', ['videos' => $videos ]);
 }
`
The same error occurs with or without the order_by. There is no other code, i would assume Laravel is performing other actions internally based on the relation

Comment: So show the models, relation definition in particular. There's `select` used somewhere.

Comment: Its there already in the video model 

`public function subscriptions()
{
 return $this->belongsToMany('App\Subscription');
}`

There are no relations defined in the Subscription Model at this time.

Comment: Hmmm. This code doesn't execute such query, that's for sure. I don't know of any bug in the Builder lately, but tell me what is your framework version exactly?

Comment: This occurs on 5.0.21 and 5.0.23

Comment: I have included the 1st 10 lines of the stack trace above

Comment: No problem on 5.0.23 with the same setup on my end. Try fresh install and recreate your models to test it.